# Comparing if 2 dates are the same day Java

Tags: java

Good day, quick question, Am trying to compare if 2 dates are the same day for the same time zone (city)Anyone have any idea why the following code holds and the other doesn't, can't seem to understand why.

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd,MMM");
Date newparsetemp = fmt.parse(parsedate);
Date currentdateparse = fmt.parse(currentdate);


  if(currentdateparse.equals(newparsetemp)){
       //code executes
  }
```

but if i do use this, the if condition doesn't hold

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); 
Date newparsetemp = fmt.parse(parsedate);
Date currentdateparse = fmt.parse(currentdate);

if(currentdateparse.equals(newparsetemp)){
   //does not 

  }
```

Comment: What are the values of `parseDate` and `currentDate`?

Comment: Are you albe to use Joda Time instead? That's always a good start to "I've got this date/time problem in Java..." Note that the code you've given doesn't mention time zones at all... do you actually *have* a time zone?

Comment: Lets see some input and debug information. ^^ On another topic, when working with time/dates in Java I would allways recommend using a thirdparty library e.g. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: If your input values are strings which only indicate the date in the same format, isn't this broadly equivalent to checking that the strings are the same?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, they are just two date objects which i get from a webservice and convert to strings..

Comment: @JonSkeet ouch!!! you know you could be right, i did not think of that!!!!  :D  i will check that tomorrow in the office.

Comment: @sparrow: Why are you converting them to strings to start with? Stop doing that :) Unnecessary string conversions are a really bad idea.

Comment: @sparrow The best thing to do is create a simple test case with a hard coded input and the erroneous output - until you do that people can only guess what is going wrong...

Comment: Just post two values for which the first snippet works and the second doesn't.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis am sorry but right now, i don't have the code with me. i would post it when i am on the work desk. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)'s [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).

```
Date data1 = ...
Date date2 = ...
new LocalDate(date1).equals(new LocalDate(date2))
```

Better yet just skip `Date` and use `LocalDate` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing after formatting to a string is an odd thing to do.  Try this instead:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(parsedate);
Calendar cal2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTime(currentdate);



cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println(cal.equals(cal2) ? "true" : "false");
```

Your comment about timezones needs clarification.  Did you mean to say

> compare if 2 dates are the same day for **different** time zones?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "comparing only the day of week", have you tried comparing the result of `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` instead?

Comment: I don't *think* it's actually talking about the day of the week - I think it's about the overall date. It's unclear at the moment though.

Comment: @Jon: Right. Then maybe Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) AND Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)

Comment: I think I'd rather use Joda Time :)

Answer (score 0):

do you agree that there is a chance that two different dates from different years, in the same month and day, can match the same day of the week?

and that there's no chance of two different dates match the same day, month and year?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually done this not too long ago in one of my Android apps,

```
public boolean isSameDay(Event otherEvent) {
    if(otherEvent == null) return false;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    try {
        Calendar otherEventDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        otherEventDate.setTime(format.parse(otherEvent.getStartTime()));
        Calendar thisEventDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        thisEventDate.setTime(format.parse(getStartTime()));
        return (otherEventDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == thisEventDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
                 otherEventDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)  == thisEventDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's the code as I did it, I'm just checking if the two events are occurring the same day. If you wish to add some more precision you'll just have to add this for yourself.